# NMEA to KML creator - open source

Tags: kml, nmea

I'm looking for an open source KML creator from NMEA file. I'd prefer it to be in c\cpp, but any other language will be fine too.

(for either windows or Linux)

Does anyone know of such thing?
(Google didn't help much)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/Source.html), an open source tool for GPS format conversion. 
You can find the code in SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpsbabel/